# Complete switch on enum in Java produces "Missing return statement" error

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Suppose, we have switch statement, that fully covers all possible cases of enum parameter, and has null-check too, will not be compiled cause of `"Missing return statement"`.

```
enum Foo {ONE,TWO}

int fooToInt(Foo foo) {
    if (foo == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    switch (foo) {
        case ONE: return 1;
        case TWO: return 2;
    }
}
```

I know, that throwing exception from `default` case or after enum, or visiting enum element instead of `switch` will fix the problem. But I do not understand technical cause of such behavior: obviously, there is no possible branch of execution, which not leads to `return` or `throw`. Also it would be great in some cases to have compile-time check that all cases are covered.

Comment: You might want to `break` after each case or at least after the last case.

Comment: It’s not really necessary to write `if (foo == null) { throw new NullPointerException(); }`, considering what will happen when `switch(foo)` is executed and `foo` is `null`…

Comment: Holger, it was written just to show that all possible branches are explicitly covered.

Answer (score 9):

Since you did not write default, the compiler added it automatically at the next line after switch block. At that point, the compiler "notice" that there is no return point from the method and gives you that error.

I've taken you example and changed but added throw of RuntimeException after the switch, like this:

```
public class Example {

   enum Foo { ONE, TWO }

    int fooToInt(Foo foo) {
        if (foo == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        switch (foo) {
            case ONE: return 1;
            case TWO: return 2;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Should not have gotten here");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

I've compiled the class and used javap -c Example.class to see the actual bytecode (see below). Notice the "default: 52" which was added by the javac. 
It leads to the block section after the switch case, and there, I've thrown RuntimeException which overwrite the need for return.

```
Compiled from "Example.java"
public class com.mprv.automation.jenkins.Example {
  public com.mprv.automation.jenkins.Example();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  int fooToInt(com.mprv.automation.jenkins.Example$Foo);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: ifnonnull     12
       4: new           #2                  // class java/lang/NullPointerException
       7: dup
       8: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/NullPointerException."<init>":()V
      11: athrow
      12: getstatic     #4                  // Field com/mprv/automation/jenkins/Example$1.$SwitchMap$com$mprv$automation$jenkins$Example$Foo:[I
      15: aload_1
      16: invokevirtual #5                  // Method com/mprv/automation/jenkins/Example$Foo.ordinal:()I
      19: iaload
      20: lookupswitch  { // 2
                     1: 48
                     2: 50
               default: 52
          }
      48: iconst_1
      49: ireturn
      50: iconst_2
      51: ireturn
      52: new           #6                  // class java/lang/RuntimeException
      55: dup
      56: ldc           #7                  // String Should not have gotten here
      58: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/RuntimeException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      61: athrow

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark here, having not read any rationale for this, but if this is not the *primary* reason for the behavior, it is at least *a* reason.

Suppose that the enum instead comes from a library which your project depends on. In the version you compile against, `ONE` and `TWO` are the only options. However, you may end up *running* against a later version (through OSGi or other solutions) that has added another value `THREE`. If `THREE` gets passed to `fooToInt`, it will reach the end of your method, and nothing will have been returned (or thrown). Oops.

This is rather unpleasant to discover at runtime, so you are forced to make a choice as to how it will be handled, even if it actually seems impossible at compile time. Some cases, like the one in your example, could probably be detected and allowed to compile, and other cases *could* have been handled differently (e.g. an implicit `throw`), but on the list of all things that could be done to improve Java, I wouldn't put that at the top.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't check if you have listed all the constants from `Foo` as `case` blocks, and thus raises and error.

Suppose that `Foo` was defined as:

```
enum Foo {ONE,TWO,THREE}
```

Then, what would your method return if you pass `Foo.THREE` as an argument?

---

As an alternative to the `switch` approach, you could add a `int` member in the `Foo` enum, and set the corresponding number for each constant:

```
enum Foo {
    ONE(1),TWO(2);

    int value;
    Foo(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This way you won't need a `switch` and the compiler will kindly ask you to set a corresponding number to any possible new `Foo` constant.

Comment: Since some compilers support the generation of warnings if you don’t list all `enum` constants, it’s not correct to say that the compiler doesn't check that—but the compiler is not *allowed* to let you get away without specifying how to handle an unknown value. After all, a new constant could be added to the `enum` type *after* the `switch` statement has been compiled.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is that the compiler doesn't actually go through your switch to check if you've implemented every case, it just checks that the existing cases correspond to actual values in **Foo** - hence it needs something, either a **default** block or a return.

Answer (score -2):

You missed the `default` block.

Because your method have to return some value.

Put **return** outside the switch statement. Or put **default** block